# grails db-generate-changelog error

Tags: grails, data-migration

Error run command:

```
grails dbm-generate-changelog changelog.groovy
```

command line output:

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dbmGenerateGormChangelog'.

> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  BUILD FAILED
  Total time: 14.887 secs
  | Error Command [dbm-generate-gorm-changelog] error: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: Did you try with `--stacktrace`?

Comment: which version of hibernate are you  using?

Comment: @quindimildev 5.1.1.Final

Comment: dbm is not compatible with hibernate 5 yet.

Comment: there is a workarround for make it work with dbm-diff

Comment: Here is the issue open https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/issues/64

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @quindimildev.  The open issue resolved my issue.  The direct post that assisted me was the following:  https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/issues/64#issuecomment-256739113

I inserted into my dependencies:

> runtime "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"